# Removing duplicates but not the empty elements, and storing the duplicate elements in another array

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to replicate my code that i have in python into Javascript as I am new to it, and i really cant find any reference for this particular problem that I have.
So, i have an array with elements, and i want to find duplicates but skip the empty spaces, but not filter them because in that case the counter that i have would break and give me a wrong value.
The array should be in it original form, not sorted.
This is the code in python:

```
lis = ["", "5", "2", "", "2", ""]

not_dupl = []
dupl = []

for i in lis:
    print(i)
    if i not in not_dupl or i =='':
        not_dupl.append(i)
    else:
        dupl.append(i)
print(not_dupl)  # expected output ["", "5", "2", "", ""]
print(dupl)  # expected output ["2"]
```

I am not sure if it exists a function 'in' in javascript that checks inside a string or array.

Comment: The empty strings are duplicate elements too, why aren't they included in `dupl`? Please post the Javascript you've tried so far.

Comment: @CertainPerformance as you see from this  `if i not in not_dupl or i ==''` where it checks if element is not in not_dup, basically unique elements, but if i == '"" then it still appends it at the not_dupl list.

Comment: So the empty string is just a special exception? There's no built-in function in JS that can do something like this all on its own, you'll have to start writing one of your own

Comment: This: _I am not sure if it exists a function 'in' in javascript that checks inside a string or array._ is the `includes` method in strings and arrays in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you are looking for *includes*:

```
const lis = ["", "5", "2", "", "2", ""];

const not_dupl = [], dupl = [];

for(const i of lis) {
  console.log(i);
  if(!not_dupl.includes(i) || i === '')
    not_dupl.push(i);
  else
    dupl.push(i);
}

console.log(not_dupl, dupl);
```

PS: `i` is a bad name for a non index, also why `lis` and not just `list`, why `not_dupl` instead of `nonDuplicates` ?

Comment: Jonas Wilms, yes thanks to you i was looking at includes method, and i managed to solve it in my own, which is i a little different from your solution but basically the same thing. As for lis, and not list, list is a reserved name in python and thats why, the same for nonDuplicates, because we are used of using underscore and not camel case notations. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of ways that you can do this, you can use `array.includes(object)` or you can check `array.indexOf(object) !== -1` the support for includes is relatively bad in internet explorer and opera, so you should be weary about using that.

```js
let lis = ["", "5", "2", "", "2", ""]

let not_dupl = [];
let dupl = [];

lis.forEach((element, index, array) => {
  if (element === "" || not_dupl.indexOf(element) === -1) {
    not_dupl.push(lis[index]);
  } else {
   dupl.push(lis[index]);
  }
})

console.log(not_dupl); //# expected output ["", "5", "2", "", ""]
console.log(dupl); //# expected output ["2"]
```

Comment: i forgot to mention that the array should not be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mylist = ["", "5", "2", "", "2", ""];
    var not_dupl =[];
    var dupl = [];
    for (var i=0; i< mylist.length; i++){
        if (not_dupl.includes(mylist[i]) === false || mylist[i]==='' ){
            not_dupl.push(mylist[i])
        } else {
            dupl.push(mylist[i])
        }
    }
    console.log(not_dupl);
    console.log(dupl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a set:

Javascript:

```
 var lis = ["", "5", "2", "", "2", ""];
 var dups = new Set();
 var dupl = a.filter(function(i){isDup=dups.has(i);dups.add(i);return isDup && i!=""});
```